# Interpretation of linear regression intercept

Tags: regression, excel

I am aware this is a very basic question. I just need clarification (for my sanity)

For this regression: [image]

Is it true to say that:

- The regression outturn records the intercept as significant. (If so - why?)
- The R-squared value is extremely small which indicates that the model explains very little of the variability of the response data around its mean.

Comment: Well, what do you think?

Comment: 1. The intercept does not appear to be significant (following the *general interpretation* of $p\leq 0.05$) so I cannot see why you say that. 2. Yes. While $R^2$ is generally a poor indicator about model performance, an $R^2$ that is less that $0.001$ is safely characterised as "bad".

Comment: After a careful review of the technical literature on statistics in this particular subject area, I found that the most accurate professional term that generally applies as a descriptor for R-squared values this low is "poopy-doopy".

Comment: Neither the intercept nor the coefficient of X are "significant" at any conventional level.  But why are you interested in the significance of the *intercept* anyway?